# Background picture not showing after editing with dconf-editor

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, dconf

To remove a desktop item (In the process of replacing nautilus with an older version, a "Computer" icon appeared on the desktop), I used `dconf-editor` to toggle the entry `show-desktop-icons` in `org.gnome.desktop.background`.

This worked, but after a reboot, the background (previously a picture) does not show. Instead: a black screen is shown.

Reading the configuration in dconf, the values set are:

```
color-shading-type: solid
draw-background: true
picture-opacity: 100
picture-options: zoom
picture-uri: file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Last_breath%E2%80%A6_by_Francisco_Javier_Epinoza_P%C3%A9rez.jpg
primary-color: #000000
secondary-color: #000000
show-desktop-icons: false
```

I've checked the location of the file: it exists as expected.

System Settings > Appearance also reports this background.

How to re-enable the background image?

Comment: You really aught to upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `dconf` misbehaves on `show-desktop-icons` and also disables the background image. Hence one has to set the flag `show-desktop-icons` back to `true`.

This brings back the desktop item, which one can correctly (i.e. not messing with the background image) disable with `gnome-tweak-tool`, section "Desktop".

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work on the exact same issue in gnome-flashback